# Manage overflow of elements on form group

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using JQuery to add span elements with text inside to a div. When the text is too large and many elements have been added, the elements overflow and exceed the panel width. How can I prevent this from happening so the elements will break to the next line? Also so they can reorder themselves if the panel width changes (window resize).

HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
   <label class="control-label "></label>
   <div class="form group" id="selected_demographics">              
   </div>
</div>
```

JQ

```
var $spanTitle = $('<span class="input-group-addon demographic-title">').text(demographic);
var $btnDeleteMap = $('<button class="btn btn-xs delete-demographic" type="button">X</button>');
$spanTitle.append($btnDeleteMap);

$('span.demographic-title:last').after($spanTitle);
```

Assume the first spanTitle has already been added, it overflows to the right.

[image]

Comment: wrap the title and put an overflow property to it

Answer (score 0):

In CSS styles use:

```
div {
  word-break:break-word
}
```